# exec command returning empty array

Tags: php, pdf

I have installed the library wkhtmltopdf [link](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) in my CentOS VPS, when I run it from my server using terminal like :  "wkhtmltopdf https://www.google.com google.pdf" I get some messages in the output as following :

---

Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done

---

and the PDF is created.

Now when I use PHP with exec command like :

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf https://www.google.com google.pdf");
var_dump($output);
?>
```

the PDF file is created and all seems ok but I get NULL as value of the $output variable. Why is the exec command not giving the same out put?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, while I don't think you understood my answer I was mistaken and it is identical to using shell_exec() so I have removed the answer. I am doing exactly this in my scripts (except I'm using backticks rather than shell_exec) so I'm now completely unsure why it's not working for you.

Comment: On reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) it occurs to me that maybe shell_exec is disabled in your php.ini?

Comment: I tried to add "2>&1 &" at the end of the exec script shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf https://www.google.com google.pdf 2>&1 &");and it is working now, so any other suggestions please?

Comment: I'm really confused now -- what exactly are you asking for? All you've done there is redirect the error output to stdout and make the program run in the background?

Comment: Wait - are you asking the difference between `shell_exec` and `exec`? In which case `exec` does not return the output, it allows you to collect it in an array which you give it as the 2nd perameter...?

Comment: I'm looking for the command run from PHP to give me the same out put as the command run from terminal. as i explained in my question

Comment: I've updated my answer - see the bottom bit -- any help?

Comment: I would not recommend backgrounding the process; PHP won't wait for the process to be complete and you may not end up getting all the output from the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably `echo` the `output` if you don't want to see a `NULL` result:

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf https://www.google.com google.pdf 2>&1");
echo($output);
```

Since the output formatting looks bad it can also be cleaned up:

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf https://www.google.com google.pdf 2>&1");
$tidyit = preg_replace("/(.[^\[]*\s\d{1,2}%)\s(?<!100%)|([=>\[]*)/","",$output);
$result = preg_replace("/]/","<br>",$tidyit);
echo($result);
```

**Result**:

```
Loading pages (1/6) 100%
Counting pages (2/6)
Object 1 of 1 Resolving links (4/6)
Object 1 of 1 Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Preparing
Page 1 of 1 Done
```

Comment: This gives me a PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion, when I use it with exec($command, $output)

Answer (score 2):

`shell_exec` and `exec` are different in that `shell_exec`'s return value is the output, whereas `exec` only gives you the last line - if you want to retrieve output using `exec` you need to pass in a 2nd parameter of the array you'd like to store the results in:

```
<?php
exec("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf https://www.google.com google.pdf",$output)
var_dump($output)
?>
```

You can also use backticks instead of `shell_exec`:

```
<?php
$output = `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf https://www.google.com google.pdf`;
var_dump($output);
?>
```

Please see [PHP Execution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php):

> PHP supports one execution operator: backticks (``). Note that these
>   are not single-quotes! PHP will attempt to execute the contents of the
>   backticks as a shell command; the output will be returned (i.e., it
>   won't simply be dumped to output; it can be assigned to a variable).
>   Use of the backtick operator is identical to shell_exec().

**Additional**:

Your code is correct, but the script is probably timing out before wkhtmltopdf is finished, meaning it never receives the return value. Try this to extend php's timeout and give it time to finish it's wkhtmltopdf process:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(60); // 60 seconds should be long enough to create your pdf
    $output = `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf https://www.google.com google.pdf`;
    var_dump($output);
?>
```

Comment: Where is the exec command in your code, the output will only print the content of the variable.

Comment: do you understand what I wrote? if I use you answer's code all I will get is the content of the output variable as output, why did you remove shell_exec in your response?

Comment: Whoops - red in the face - my answer is identical to using shell_exec()!

Comment: I've updated this answer - I'm hoping what you are after is in there somewhere